# Report with slicers sent via email as attachment

Tags: report, reporting, email-attachments, slicers

I need to develop a report that contains slicers and gets sent as an attachment via email daily. The data for my report are in a Power BI dataset and I have to use the Power BI dataset because that's the only way I can access the data. What tools can help me develop this report?

1. Tried Power BI subscription but doesn't work because it exports in PPT or PDF format only which doesn't have the ability to use the slicers.
2. Connected dataset to Tableau but I don't have Tableau server to enable subscription.
3. Develop in Excel but need to filter each table separately. Looking to have one filter only for all tables.

Please advise. Thanks in advance